# How to move an ASP .NET application to a Web Server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment

I have an ASP .net Web Application already deployed on my local machine (virtual directory/IIS are configured). I used the Publish tool from Visual Studio. Now I want to move it to our Webserver (I have the IP adress and the appropriate credentials).

How should I do this?

**EDIT**
By the way, I'm asking because I don't know if there is a specific way to do this? I can do it manually by moving the files to the remote computer and configure IIS approriately.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the IIS on the remote server is configures correctly, you can use the publish functionality in VS - this is essentially just a copy of the built assemblies and the required resources (aspx, ascx, images and other static content). You will still need to configure IIS on the remote server to use the copies files.

Other then that, you can create an installer package that will do all that for you. This means you will need to RDP to the remove server and run the installer there.